# Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't see my Samsung anymore

Tags: usb, connection

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and my PC ist charging my Samsung phone via USB but can't see it. It's not the USB cable. It's charging but not to see on PC. İt works on my Laptop.

EDIT output from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 2357:0109 TP-Link TL-WN823N v2/v3 [Realtek RTL8192EU] 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6340 Microdia Camera 
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy A5 (MTP) 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0480:a006 Toshiba America Inc External Disk 1.5TB 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 248a:8514 Maxxter Wireless Receiver 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: do you mean MTP file transfer? do you enable it from the notification? can you post `lsusb` while your phone is plugged in please

Comment: It says the Samsung phone is connected to USB, and using the MTP protocol.

Comment: where can't you see it? what are you trying to do, what do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: I am trying to connect my Samsung with my Ubuntu 22.04 to transfer pictures. But although the cell phone is charging, it cannot be seen on the PC. The settings on the phone are ok because it works on the laptop